# Posting form to custom PHP script within Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I added this contact form to a custom page template in wordpress:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="inc/mail.php" method="POST">
    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
    <textarea  id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comments / Questions"></textarea>
    <input class="button" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And I created a PHP page to handle the form once posted:

```
<?php   
// Gather form data
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$client = "";
$clientname = "";
$password = "";

if($name && $email && $comments) {

    // Create instance of PHP mailer
    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = $client;
    $mail->Password = $password;

    $mail->From = $client;
    $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->AddAddress($client, $clientname);

    $mail->IsHTML(false);   

    $formcontent="From: \n $name \n\n Email: \n $email \n\n Phone: \n $phone \n\n Comments: \n $comments";
    $mail->Subject = "Miss Mary's Inquiry";
    $mail->Body = $formcontent;

    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }
}
```

?>

The form and handler work perfectly outside of Wordpress, but I think Wordpress is preventing the PHP script (mail.php) from being accessed. Is there a way to post the form to my PHP script without Wordpress / htaccess interfering?

Thanks!

Comment: Oh man, this is so wide open to expoitation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send mails in wordpress try using plugins. There are tons of wordpress plugins for that.
[Conatact form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) is the one which I like the most. Still you can develop your own but create it as plugin. You can convert the above code into a shortcode plugin. [Check this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

`wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments )`

This function is normally used for sending mails in wordpress